# Python request.get response with a single word and i tried different headers

Tags: python, python-requests

hey everyone I am trying to scrape this website but for some reason, it's not scarping. its really appreciate it if someone can give me a hand with this problem I have tried to use a different user agent but it's not working for some reason. for page content, it prints b'' and for the soup its empty

thanks in advance here's my code:

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
url = "https://www.carrefourjordan.com/mafjor/en/c/deals?currentPage=1&filter=&nextPageOffset=0&pageSize=60&sortBy=relevance"
headers = {'User-Agent':'test'}
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(page.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
print(soup)

** These the 3 different headers I used **


```headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}```
````

Comment: If ti doesn't work from a browser, why should it work from `requests`?

Comment: i can access it from a browser and its working fine but if I am using requests.get its not getting anything

Comment: Clear cookoes and re run the url. It does't load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the right cookies first. so you'll need to use a session

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/5.1)'}
 
url = "https://www.carrefourjordan.com/mafjor/en/c/deals?currentPage=1&filter=&nextPageOffset=0&pageSize=60&sortBy=relevance"
with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    # get the cookies first
    s.get("https://www.carrefourjordan.com")
    
    page = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
```